# How can I check if a DateTime lies between a certain date range without taking the year into account?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm cognitively struggling with a probably fairly simple problem. Given a certain `DateTime`, how can I verify that this date (without accounting its year) is in between two other dates?

An example:

```
DateTime toCheck = new DateTime(1900, 3, 4);
DateTime min = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1);
DateTime max = new DateTime(2024, 12, 31);
// True - 'toCheck' is between 'min' and 'max'
```

In the snippet above, `toCheck` is in between `min` and `max` because *3rd April* is between *1st January* and *31st December*. I can easily verify this with something like `new DateTime(min.Year, toCheck.Month, toCheck.Day) >= min && new DateTime(max.Year, toCheck.Month, toCheck.Day) <= max;`.

However, I realized this gets more complicated when years overlap. For instance, in the following scenario, *January 1st* is between *December 1st* and *February 1st* but my check fails (obviously).

```
DateTime toCheck = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
DateTime min = new DateTime(2024, 12, 1);
DateTime max = new DateTime(2025, 2, 1);
// False - but should actually be True :(
```

I just can't wrap my head around writing a general, bulletproof solution. Any help is highly appreciated.

[Link to dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/76kUBZ)

Comment: How would you compare to 29th February?

Comment: Good question, let's assume that `toCheck` can never be that date and I treat this case separately in advance.

Comment: [DateTime.DayOfYear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofyear?view=net-8.0) ? _"Gets the day of the year represented by this instance."_ - Take this from all 3 and compare them? Not sure how leap-years would handle this, though. Overlapping Years must be handled differently, too.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay If his min-max allows Dez,Jan&Feb (so crossing new year) then August is outside the range?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay could you please elaborate? I would've thought anything from November 30th to Janurary 31st doesn't fall in between the timespan.

Comment: ^^ Could you run your unit tests on this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xc1rhK ?

Comment: @Fildor `min = new DateTime(2024, 12, 1); max = new DateTime(2026, 1, 31);` will fail but it should be invalid having a range > 1 year or easily fixable ;)

Comment: @Ralf I was indeed assuming a period < 1 year, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic is simple:

- format all three dates in MMdd format for straight forward comparison
- compare the three values as follows:
- if min <= max then:

  - is_between = (to_check >= min && to_check <= max)
- else

  - is_between = (to_check >= min || to_check <= max)

So for example if you have [Dec 1, Feb 1] range, you would check if date is greater than/equal to Dec 1 OR less than/equal to Feb 1.

Converting the above logic to the language of your choice is trivial.

[dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cWznjM)

Comment: Sideeffect: would also solve the leap-year problem.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by *formatting to MMdd* in more detail? I doubt you suggest coverting the dates in strings. Also you can't have dates like `new DateTime(null, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Use DateTime.toString to format the dates. It should be 4 digit zero padded string e.g . Jan 31 would be 0131.

Comment: @Fildor No, if the problem is whether the month day combination of toCheck exists between min and max dates (I feel this makes more sense). Also crossing over 1 year hasn't been taken into account.

Comment: @shingo that's the 'else' branch. Periods >1 year don't make sense in this context.

Comment: @Fildor What I mean is, e.g. `toCheck=2-29, min=2024-12-1, max=2025-3-1`, since 2025 is not a leap year, Feb.29 should not be considered within this range.

Comment: @shingo Ah, I see. I think we need to presuppose a _valid_ date is input. As OP said before in comments to the question, they would handle that situation separately. What I meant was if 29.2. _is_ a valid date, then this solution will handle it correctly in contrast to my answer, which needs to handle both externally.

Comment: @shingo my guess is that OP has a list of events that recur every year within certain month-day intervals. The toCheck date could be, for example, today's date which could be 29 Feb 2024. The start and end dates need to be specified in a specific format e.g. if the event occurs "throughout february" then min and max must be set to [2000-02-01, 2000-02-29] (any year that has 29th feb). The logic works for that case. I'll try to come up with some tests.

Comment: Brilliant solution! I extended your answer with a `if (min.AddYears(1) <= max) is_between = true` to allow ranges >1 year.

Answer (score 3):

Approach based on `DayOfYear` :

```
public static bool Check(DateTime toCheck, DateTime min, DateTime max)
        => Check(toCheck.DayOfYear, min.DayOfYear, max.DayOfYear);
    
public static bool Check(int toCheck, int min, int max)
{
    return min <= max
        ? min <= toCheck && toCheck <= max
        : !(min > toCheck && toCheck > max); // min and max are on opposite side of new year

        // in the latter case we test that the
        // check date is NOT BETWEEN max and min 
        // the condition can also be written as
        // min <= toCheck || toCheck <= max
    }
}
```

Ran against your examples: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cca1Uz results in

```
true
true
```

I did not test leap-year, but you said in comments, you would handle that separately.
Mind that [Salman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78102335/982149) is similar but fixes this problem.

Note: **This assumes a period strictly < 1 year.**

Answer (score 2):

You could use this class that should work as expected:

```
public class DateRangeEvaluator
{
    public DateRangeEvaluator(DateOnly minDate, DateOnly maxDate)
    {
        if (minDate > maxDate) throw new ArgumentException("MinDate must not be greater than MaxDate");
        MinDate = minDate;
        MaxDate = maxDate;
    }

    public DateOnly MinDate { get; }
    public DateOnly MaxDate { get; }

    public bool IsBetween(DateOnly checkDate)
    {
        if (MinDate.Year != MaxDate.Year)
        {
            bool checkMaxDate = checkDate.Month < MinDate.Month;
            int newCheckDateYear = checkMaxDate ? MaxDate.Year : MinDate.Year;
            checkDate = new(newCheckDateYear, checkDate.Month, checkDate.Day);
            return checkMaxDate ? checkDate <= MaxDate : checkDate >= MinDate;
        }

        DateOnly compareDateMin = new(checkDate.Year, MinDate.Month, MinDate.Day);
        DateOnly compareDateMax = new(checkDate.Year, MaxDate.Month, MaxDate.Day);
        return checkDate >= compareDateMin && checkDate <= compareDateMax;
    }
}
```

Some tests including yours:

```
DateRangeEvaluator validator = new(new(2024, 12, 1), new(2025, 2, 1));
DateOnly startDate = new(1900, 10, 1);
foreach (var date in Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(startDate.AddMonths))
{
    bool isInBetween = validator.IsBetween(date);
    Console.WriteLine($"Date: {date} between {validator.MinDate} and {validator.MaxDate}: {isInBetween}");
}
```

Test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HTa1Jx

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extract the years in the range and apply that year to the date to check to see if it is within the range.

```
public static bool IsBetween(DateTime min, DateTime max, DateTime toCheck)
{
    var numberOfYears = max.Year - min.Year + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++)
    {
        var date = new DateTime(min.Year + i, toCheck.Month, toCheck.Day);
        if (date >= min && date <= max)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check and or condition with max date year for both smaller and greater condition. It will take care of every situation.

```
if((new DateTime(min.Year, toCheck.Month, toCheck.Day) >= min  
    && new DateTime(max.Year, toCheck.Month, toCheck.Day) <= max)
||
    (new DateTime(max.Year, toCheck.Month, toCheck.Day) >= min 
    && new DateTime(max.Year, toCheck.Month, toCheck.Day) <= max)
)
{
// Code for true condition
}
```